# In Makefiles, how to re-enable --print-directory in a sub-directory when --no-print-directory has been set?

Tags: makefile, flags

First, let me say that I am aware of the cons of using recursive Makefiles. So if you are here just to tell me don't use it, please don't.

Imagine this directory structure:

```
rootdir
`-- subdir
    |-- a
    |-- b
    `-- c
```

Let's say the Makefile on `rootdir` reads like this:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    # build some stuff
    $(MAKE) -C subdir
```

and the one in `subdir` reads like this:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    # nothing here except redirecting make to each of the subdirectories
    $(MAKE) -C a
    $(MAKE) -C b
    $(MAKE) -C c
```

and another Makefile in each of `a`, `b` and `c` folders building something.

Since the Makefile in `subdir` serves no purpose except redirecting make, I want make not to print: `Entering directory rootdir/subdir` and `Leaving directory rootdir/subdir` to clean up the output a bit.

On the other hand, since there are commands being executed in the subfolders `a`, `b` and `c`, I **do** want make to print these outputs. Here's what I thought would work:

`rootdir`'s Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    # build some stuff
    $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C subdir
```

`subdir`'s Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    # nothing here except redirecting make to each of the subdirectories
    $(MAKE) --print-directory -C a
    $(MAKE) --print-directory -C b
    $(MAKE) --print-directory -C c
```

The problem is, once the `--no-print-directory` is given to make when calling make for `subdir`, `--print-directory` doesn't enable it again when calling make for `a`, `b` or `c`.

So my question is, how can I re-enable printing directories when a parent make has disabled it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make command line flags get communicated to sub-makes via [`MAKEFLAGS` variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-MAKEFLAGS-404). You may like to replace `--no-print-directory` (if any) from `MAKEFLAGS` with `w` manually before invoking the sub-makes:

```
${MAKE} MAKEFLAGS="$(subst --no-print-directory,w,${MAKEFLAGS})" -C ...
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Although I was hoping for something cleaner!